# Compute exterior derivative of $1$-form

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, differential-forms

Let $\omega = xy \, dx + z \, dy - yz \, dz$ be the $1$-form. Calculate $d\omega$. So I have

\begin{align}
d \omega &= (y \, dx +  x \, dy) \, \wedge dx + dz \, \wedge dy - (z \, dy + y \, dz) \, \wedge dz \\
&=y \, dx \, \wedge dx + x \, dy \, \wedge dx + dz \, \wedge dy - z \, dy \wedge dz - y \, dz \wedge dz \\
&=x \, dy \wedge dx + (1+z) \, dz \wedge dy && \text{as $da \, \wedge da =0$, $da \, \wedge db = - db \, \wedge da$}
\end{align}

Did I compute it correctly? I know I ended up with a $2-$form so something I did was correct.

Comment: It looks good to me. I end up with the same result.

Comment: Sweet, thanks @Lukas !!